# to duplicate vs to reproduce

Tags: expressions

I am facing this

> Try to duplicate the problem yourself.

But normally we use `reproduce` in place of `duplicate`.

Here http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/duplicate there is no synonym like `reproduce`.

So my question  is`Try to reproduce the problem yourself.` a correct sentence?

And why do  `reproduce` is not marked as a synonym for `duplicate`?

Comment: *Reproduce* ***is*** given as a synonym at your link: but you have to select the "verb" tab instead of the "adj" tab.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has overlooked a section of the thesaurus cited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Duplicate* means to take an existing X and make a copy of it.

For example, you *duplicate* a piece of paper by putting it through a copier.

*Reproduce* can be used to mean the above, but it can also mean make a new copy of X by building X from scratch.

So by saying *reproduce a problem*, we mean try to re*create* it, i.e. start from where you do not experience the problem and perform the steps that create it again.